# How do I delete my credit card information from Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I once added a credit card to my Google account to buy some apps, but now I would like to remove that information. I cannot find any settings, where I could delete it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you must connect your credit card to [Google Wallet](https://wallet.google.com) to use it in the [Play store](https://play.google.com/store). To remove your credit card from Wallet:

1. Login to your account on [Google Wallet](https://wallet.google.com/manage).
2. Click *Payment Methods* on the left side of the page.
3. Click *Delete* next to the card you would like to remove.

Comment: It still works. Except the option is now titled "Remove". I had many outdated cards stored in there, together with my previous home addresses. It's a good thing to clean that up once in a while. IMHO, Google should really remove outdated cards automatically. There's no purpose in keeping record of old cards. Transaction history is another story.

Comment: If you had a Google Cloud service account you might find this process to be ineffective, or to lead to a cycle of removal pages that do not work, where Google cloud service subscriptions to not fall in the same category as other subscriptions.  For this, the most expedient solution may be to call Google  cloud services: 1-877-355-5787

Comment: Google will not allow you to remove the **last** card from your account. Trying to do so causes it to prompt you to enter a new card, and you cannot complete the removal without supplying a new card. This is highly annoying for my case, where I have just canceled my (lost) card and am awaiting a replacement.

Comment: Clarification: I have the Family Library set up, and that is the pseudo-subscription that is requiring I keep a card active. Presumably without this, it would let me delete the card.